# Заполнение массива с++

Tags: c++, массивы

Как заполнить двумерный массив числами от 1 к 15 в разброс и что бы они не повторялись.Мой вариант очень долгий. Возможно можно как-то по другому.И чем проще тем лучше

```
void filling (int ar[][size])
{
    srand(time(0));
    for (int r=0; r<size; r++)
        for (int c=0; c<size; c++)
        {
        res:
            ar[r][c]=rand()%16;
            for (int e=r; r>=0; e--)
                 for (int x=c; c>=0; x--)
                      if (ar[r][c] == ar[e][x]) goto res;
        }
}
```

Comment: void filling (int ar[][size])
{
    srand(time(0));
    for(int r =0;r<size;r++)
    for(int c =0;c<size;c++)
    {
        res:
        ar[r][c]=rand()%16;
        for(int e =r;r>=0;e--)
        for(int x=c;c>=0;x--)
        if(ar[r][c]==ar[e][x])
        goto res;
    }
}

Comment: только я не понел, вам нужен массив с числами от  1  до 15, чтобы они не повторялись, тогда массив не должен  иметь более  15  элементов? Или я неправильно понел?

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример с [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/). Думаю, это как раз то, что Вам надо. основная идея - заполняете массив числами из нужного диапазона, а потом просто случайно перемешиваете.

```
// random_shuffle example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::random_shuffle
#include <vector>       // std::vector
#include <ctime>        // std::time
#include <cstdlib>      // std::rand, std::srand

// random generator function:
int myrandom (int i) { return std::rand()%i;}

int main () {
  std::srand ( unsigned ( std::time(0) ) );
  std::vector<int> myvector;

 // set some values:
 for (int i=1; i<16; ++i) myvector.push_back(i); // 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...

 // using built-in random generator:
 std::random_shuffle ( myvector.begin(), myvector.end() );

 // using myrandom:
 std::random_shuffle ( myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), myrandom);

 // print out content:
 std::cout << "myvector contains:";
 for (std::vector<int>::iterator it=myvector.begin(); it!=myvector.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;

  std::cout << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Пример немного избыточен, т.к. там показано как для перемешивания использовать еще и свою функцию (там можно не только равномерное распределение использовать). И естественно, для большей эффективности, можно еще добавить резервирование места в векторе перед добавлением элементов. Но для маленьких выборок - и так сойдет. Главная строчка здесь: `std::random_shuffle ( myvector.begin(), myvector.end() );`.

Что касается двумерности... В функцию его можно передавать как одномерный `int *arr`, но не забудьте передать и правильный размер. И потом можно просто скопировать содержимое вектора в Ваш массив (если по какой-то причине нельзя изначально работать с векторами).

Comment: это не массив,  и достаточно  2 строки

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, Что не массив? Вектор? Да, это контейнер. Я целиком привел пример из документации с нужной функцией. Да, достаточно было вообще обойтись ссылкой на сайт, но тут вроде как есть правила, что одну ссылку нельзя.

Comment: человеку нужно заполнить массив

Answer (score 0):

```
void filling (int ar[][4]) {   
   std::vector<int> v(15, 1);
   std::partial_sum(v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin());
   std::random_shuffle(v.begin(), v.end());
   std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ar[0]);
}
```

собственно можно заполнить так любой массив с любым количеством цифр.
Можно например и так

```
int f() {
    static int k = 0;
    return ++k;
}
void filling (int ar[][4]) { 
    std::generate(m[0], &m[3][3], f);
    std::random_shuffle(m[0], &m[3][3]);
}
```

Comment: А зачем промежуточный vector? Неужели сложно написать shuffle?

Comment: @avp, вы правы, конечно можно, просто так написал для наглядности, что если можно в векторе хранить, то просто убрать последную строчку...

Answer (score 0):

Беспонтово и быстро заполнить такой массив можно, используя линейный конгруэнтный генератор как для значения, так и для индекса массива

```
void filling(int ar[][size]) {

    int *ar1 = &ar[0][0];    // массив любой мерности в c++ хранится смежно
    int m = 16;              // модуль ЛКГ
    int a = 5;               // множитель ЛКГ
    int c = 7;               // смещение ЛКГ
    int x = rand() % m;      // начальное значение элемента массива
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        x = (a * x + c) % m; // очередное значение элемента массива
        ar1[i] = x;          // запиcываем
}   }
```

При указанных в примере коэффициентах будет выдана последовательность из 16-и неповторяющих чисел, которая используется в качестве элементов массива по индексу, равному счетчику цикла. 
Можно и наоборот -- ЛКГ генерирует индексы, а пишутся счетчики цикла.

Требования, которым должны удовлетворяь коэффициенты и модуль ЛКГ, приведены в википедии. Приведенный алгоритм без изменений работает для любых массивов любой размерности.